# Logged out from facebook and when login it shows me the same page

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ios5

I have used the facebook sdk for posting a photo on a profile. When I post the photo for the first time, Safari opens up and shows me facebook's login page. I enter the usename and password and then post the picture. Now, for a button i coded the logout functionality like so:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Again, I post photo with a different username and password but the Facebook login page does not open. It says that the last page like this you have alreday register this app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756821/how-to-logout-from-facebook/23756982#23756982). Basically doing this

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

will close the **in-memory** session (within your app). If the login is made through Safari, it's in Safari where the session is still open, and I'm afraid you've got nothing to do with that.

**EDIT 1:** I noticed that you're the author of the mentioned question. The actual subject behind both questions is the same: where the Facebook session is opened. If your app forwards to the Safari app and there a web session is opened 8whatever it is, in facebook.com, google.com or whatever), you have nothing to do with that, it's a Safari responsibility).

Think it this way: imagine you have a button that opens any website in Safari (with `openURL:` method). If you then navigate to facebook.com and log in, and then you come back to Facebook, you can not tell Safari to log out from facebook.com from your app. What's happening in your code is basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to delete the cookies as per FB sdk

```
FBSession* session = [FBSession activeSession];
[session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[session close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];

NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                           [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://facebook.com/"]];

for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

And if you storing the images using any singletons , clear those at logout